# Is there any tooltip library out there for onClick event of an input element?

Tags: css, onclick, tooltip

I have a form in which I which would like to display tooltips for various input elements. Also, I want the tooltip to show on onClick event. Just wondering if there are any plugins or libraries out there for this. And all this using pure css. I have googled and come across a few, but all of them are triggered by onHover event.

I have searched in here but the best I've found is the approach of hiding/showing a div element with the desired tip. However, its messing up the position of my elements and rendering the whole form a maze.

I want something more neat. Any help?

Comment: Pure CSS? Unfortunately, are not consistent solutions. Why you don't go with JavaScript?

Comment: @Guilherme Alright, can you suggest any good js plugin?

Comment: [qTip2 is a good choice](http://qtip2.com/).